# "415 Unsupported Media Type" for Content-Type "application/csp-report" in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a content security policy that causes Chrome to post a report, but the action that receives the report returns "415 Unsupported Media Type". I understand this is because the post has a Content-Type of "application/csp-report". How do I add this as a allowed content type in Core 3.1 (its basically just json).

Action

```
// https://anthonychu.ca/post/aspnet-core-csp/
[HttpPost][Consumes("application/csp-report")]
public IActionResult Report([FromBody] CspReportRequest request)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Cut down version of model

```
public class CspReportRequest
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "csp-report")]
    public CspReport CspReport { get; set; }
}

public class CspReport
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "document-uri")]
    public string DocumentUri { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following example shows how to add support to the `SystemTextJsonInputFormatter` for handling additional media-types:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    var jsonInputFormatter = options.InputFormatters
        .OfType<SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>()
        .Single();

    jsonInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/csp-report");
});
```

This is a two-step process:

1. Interrogate the configured list of input-formatters to find the `SystemTextJsonInputFormatter`.
2. Add `application/csp-report` to its existing list of supported media-types (`application/json`, `text/json`, and `application/*+json`).

---

If you're using Json.NET instead of `System.Text.Json`, the approach is *similar*:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    var jsonInputFormatter = options.InputFormatters
        .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter>()
        .First();

    jsonInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/csp-report");
})
```

There are two small differences:

1. The type is `NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter` instead of `SystemTextJsonInputFormatter`.
2. There are *two* instances of this type in the collection, so we target the first (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146684/csp-report-endpoint-in-asp-net-core/57223057#57223057) for the specifics).

---

See [Input Formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#input-formatters) in the ASP.NET Core docs to learn more about those.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add that the accepted solution did not work for me. (.NET Core 3.1) I have the exact same use case regarding the CSP reports. When trying to use NewtonSoft and modifying the InputFormatter `NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter` to accept media header type `application/csp-report`, I would always get an exception saying the inputformatter could not be found (with or without `.AddNewtonsoftJson();`)

I managed to solve the problem by doing the following:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
services.AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
      .PostConfigure<IOptions<JsonOptions>, IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>, ArrayPool<char>, ObjectPoolProvider, ILoggerFactory>(
          (mvcOptions, jsonOpts, newtonJsonOpts, charPool, objectPoolProvider, loggerFactory) =>
          {
              var formatter = mvcOptions.InputFormatters.OfType<NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter>().First(i => i.SupportedMediaTypes.Contains("application/json"));
              formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/csp-report"));
              mvcOptions.InputFormatters.RemoveType<NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter>();
              mvcOptions.InputFormatters.Add(formatter);
          });
```

My model and the controller action are the same as the ones posted in the question.

(I derived my solution from [How to configure two JSON serializers and select the correct one based on the route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650907/how-to-configure-two-json-serializers-and-select-the-correct-one-based-on-the-ro))

Comment: This worked for me with a slight adjustment I used `JsonInputFormatter` instead of `NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter`

Comment: Accepted answer did not work, but this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem last week and found an alternative solution using my own [custom formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```c#
using CspReportLogger.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CspReportLogger.Formatters
{
  public class CSPReportInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
  {
    public CSPReportInputFormatter()
    {
      // Specify the custom media type.
      SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/csp-report"));
      SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
    {
      // Let ASP interrupt deserialization
      var cancellationToken = context.HttpContext.RequestAborted;

      // Avoid InvalidCastException, pull type from controller
      var modelType = context.ModelType;

      // Deserialize the body using our models and the JsonSerializer.
      var report = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(context.HttpContext.Request.Body, modelType, null, cancellationToken);
      return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(report);
    }
  }
}
```

Which has to be registered in Startup.cs of course:

```c#
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddControllers(options =>
      {
        options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new CSPReportInputFormatter());
      });
    }
```

I wish I had seen [Kirk Larkin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813295/12730491) earlier, as it obviously is more concise.

I suppose the custom formatter solution is helpful, if you want to accept body types that aren't valid json though.

Comment: btw asp core 3.1, this answer of creating a custom text input formatter is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to rm-code for this. I did have to make a few changes because I was getting a null value at:

```
var report = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(context.HttpContext.Request.Body, modelType, null, cancellationToken);
```

Here is what finally worked for me.

```
using Namespace.WebUI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CSPReportInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public CSPReportInputFormatter()
    {
        // Specify the custom media type.
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/csp-report"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);
        string responseString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CspReportRequest>(responseString);

        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(data);
    }
}
```