# NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter is not available as InputFormatter in .NET5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I have NET5 application and in statup I have configured the application to use `Newtonsoft` instead of `System.Text.Json.` For posting CSP report I want to add `application/csp-report` as a supported media type.

Even though I have configured to use Newtonsoft using `AddNewtonsoftJson`, the `NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter` is still not available as inputformatter. The following code returns null
when try to find in InputFormatters collection.

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {   
    services.AddControllersWithViews(config =>
    {
        var jsonInputFormatter = options.InputFormatters
           .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter>()
           .First();
         
         //jsonInputFormatter  is null here
         
        jsonInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/csp-report")
    })
    // Use Newtonsoft’s Json.NET instead of System.Text.Json.
    .AddNewtonsoftJson((options)=> 
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

based on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811255/415-unsupported-media-type-for-content-type-application-csp-report-in-asp-ne) . The accepted answer in that post did not work for me. However the other suggested work around by @Vincent Rutten did work

```
 services.AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
              .PostConfigure<IOptions<JsonOptions>, IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>, ArrayPool<char>, ObjectPoolProvider, ILoggerFactory>(
                  (mvcOptions, jsonOpts, newtonJsonOpts, charPool, objectPoolProvider, loggerFactory) =>
                  {
                      var formatter = mvcOptions.InputFormatters.OfType<NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter>().First(i => i.SupportedMediaTypes.Contains("application/json"));
                      formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/csp-report"));
                      mvcOptions.InputFormatters.RemoveType<NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter>();
                      mvcOptions.InputFormatters.Add(formatter);
                  });
```